# How to generate dummy variables for only specific values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a pandas dataframe column filled with country codes for 100 countries. I want to use these to do a regression, but I only want to create dummy variables for specific countries in my dataset.

I thought this would work:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.CountryCode, prefix='cc_')
df_and_dummies = pd.concat([df,dummies[dummies['cc_US', 'cc_GB']]], axis=1)
df_and_dummies
```

But it gives me the error:

> `KeyError: ('cc_US', 'cc_GB')`

My dataframe currently looks something like:

```
dframe = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'],
                'CountryCode': ['UK', 'US', 'RU']})
dframe
```

[image: no dummies]

But I want it to look like this:

[image: with dummy variables]

Is there a simple way to specify which values you want included in the `get_dummies` method, or is there another way to identify specific dummy variables?

Comment: Do you want `dummies[dummies.isin(['cc_US', 'cc_GB', 'cc_DE'])]`? Otherwise, can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @joris That doesn't seems to do the trick. I added an example to the post. Thanks for your kind attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dummies is looking like this:

```
In [25]: dummies
Out[25]:
   cc_RU  cc_UK  cc_US
0      0      1      0
1      0      0      1
2      1      0      0
```

To select certain columns of this, you can provide a list of column names within the [] getitem:

```
In [27]: dummies[['cc_US', 'cc_UK']]
Out[27]:
   cc_US  cc_UK
0      0      1
1      1      0
2      0      0
```

So you actually missed just a [ bracket.
Full code becomes then:

```
In [29]: pd.concat([df, dummies[['cc_US', 'cc_UK']]], axis=1)
Out[29]:
   A  B CountryCode  cc_US  cc_UK
0  a  b          UK      0      1
1  b  a          US      1      0
2  a  c          RU      0      0
```

Comment: Line 27 above returns: `KeyError: "['cc_US' 'cc_UK'] not in index"` for me. Hmmm.

Comment: Did you check that you used the correct column names? (eg not with double underscore? as `dummies = pd.get_dummies(dframe.CountryCode, prefix='cc')` with your example dataframe from above (prefix without underscore, which is automatically added)).

Comment: that extra underscore was the problem! I didn't realize `prefix` auto-appends that. Much thanks for the help.